# python selenium - chromedriver change proxy in one session

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the following code to set a proxy for chromedriver:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as options
ops = options()
ops.add_argument('--proxy-server=PROXY:PORT')
browser1 = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path='NUL', executable_path=info['location'] + '//Variables//Common//Browsers//chromedriver.exe', options=ops, desired_capabilities={'binary_location': 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'})
```

Is there a way to **change the proxy without reopening the browser**?